# Can we create a DecorView in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing custom keyboard. I am placing the custom keyboard in DecorView. Here I am facing on issue. If any popup showing then my keyboard is placed behind the popup. I noticed in layout manager that there are two decorview is created. my keyboard is placed in behind decorview. I tried `myView.bringToFront();` But not working. So I decided to create new decorView and place my keyboard in that view. Please any one can help me to create a new decorView.

[image]